# how to change the extension of a File using java?

Tags: java

I want to rename, or convert, a bunch of files with the extension m4a to mp3 files. I could just rename them all manually but I thought that it I could do it using java, so from things that I found from other peoples questions I wrote a program, i got a lot of errors when i tried different things so i edited it to remove the errors, and left it in a way that would hopefully be easy for someone to determine what I wanted and or trying to do. What did i do wrong? How do I fix it?

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileConverter {
    File folder = new File("/Users/noah/Desktop/HeadphoneMusic/");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    String p;
   File f1,f2;
    public void convert(){
       for (int i=0; i<listOfFiles.length;i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                p = new String(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                f1 = new File("newFileName(p)");
                listOfFiles[i].renameTo(f1);
            }
        }
    }
    public String newFileName(String name){
        String newName="";
        for(int i=0; i<name.length()-3;i++){
            newName+=name.charAt(i);
        }
        newName+="mp3";
        return newName;

    }

}

public class Tester {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileConverter mp3 = new FileConverter();
        mp3.convert();



    }

}
```

So i changed it to this:

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileConverter {
    File folder = new File("/Users/noah/Desktop/HeadphoneMusic/");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    String oldFilename;
    File f1,f2;
    public void convert(){
        for (int i=0; i<listOfFiles.length;i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                oldFilename = new String(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                String newFilename = oldFilename.replaceAll("/.m4a$", ".mp3");
                File f1 = new File(listOfFiles[i].getParentFile(), newFilename);
                listOfFiles[i].renameTo(f1);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileConverter mp3 = new FileConverter();
        mp3.convert();
    }
}
```

but when I check the folder containing the files, nothing is changed. What did I do wrong?

Comment: "i got a lot of errors" and what were those errors?

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking specific questions about specific things you don't understand.  A question like "Here's a program with a lot of errors, fix them all for me" is not appropriate for this site.  Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: the version of the program did not have any syntax errors. I was just trying to say that i tried to do research and figure it out myself but the program I showed was as far as I was able to get.

Comment: Note that `"/.m4a$"` is not what I suggested. That matches a slash, any character (other than newline), then `m4a`, then the end of the string. You need to match a literal `.`, then `m4a`, then the end of the string. Compare your regex and mine carefully. (Edit: I was missing an escape. But know that `/.` and `\.` mean very different things in regexes).

Comment: Thank you it works now. i put "/.m4a$" because it said I was missing an escape key so I thought you meant / but accidentally typed \. I did not realize that you meant \\. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate things.

The new filename is trivially calculated with a regex:

```
String newFilename = oldFilename.replaceAll("\\.m4a$", ".mp3");
```

but you could also have done it like this:

```
String newFilename = oldFilename.substring(0, oldFilename.length() - 3) + "mp3";
```

which is similar to your method, but way more efficient. It also assumes that all of the files are `m4a` files, ending with `.m4a`;  that *might* be true, but it's better not to assume, just in case you run the code on the wrong directory.

---

Also, [`File.getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName()) doesn't give you enough of the path to construct a new `File` correctly. Use `File.getParentFile()` to get the directory containing the file, then use this to construct a `File` in the same directory as the original file:

```
File f1 = new File(listOfFiles[i].getParentFile(), newFilename);
```

Comment: so i changed it, but when i check the folder containing the files, and nothing changed. what did i do wrong?

Comment: I'd guess the problem is that you're not descending into directories. Think about how you'd need to change your code if `listOfFiles[i].isDir()` is true. Hint: don't use member variables.

Comment: By the way: dry run your code before you run it on real data and destroy it. Change the `renameTo` line to simply print out the old and new filenames, to make sure it does the right thing safely. *Only when it does* should you make it actually rename the files.